# dojo: How can I inherit from a window class and make a custum one containing additional stuff?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dojo, window

Can I inherit from a window class in **dojo** 1.8 ? I want to make my custom window with some additional elements in it. It will be very useful because I need to reuse it many times.

Comment: with any javascript object you should be able to add whatever properties and functions you want to it. objects in javascript don't have a firm type (class) definition that they must adhere to.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying now. I hope somebody post some snippet too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not dojo specific but in javascript you can add properties and methods to an object willy nilly.

```
// assuming you myWindow is an object
myWindow.myProperty = "Test";
myWindow.myFunction = function(arg){ alert("Hello "+arg); };
```

Augmenting an object in this way is what they refer to as monkey-patching and it can even be done to native types.

Comment: thanks. So how to structure my app better? I mean - may be I need a write function in some file and when I want to initialize my custom object I add pass my function like this:
       
        `myWindow.myFunction = myInitCustomFunction();` ?

Comment: you could also make a function which adds all the functionality you need to a passed in window object. so `function makeWindowCool(win){ win.myFunction = myInitCustomFunction();` then you can just create your window as normal and then call `makeWindowCool(myWindow);`

Comment: worth noting as well creating a function like that you are not limited to just adding properties to the window you can call the `myInitCustomerFunction()` and do anything else you need to make the window behave like you want it to.